# How to move number in Text to number?

Tags: cobol

I would like to ask, how to move number in Text, e.g: 01 A   PIC X(6) value "200030", to a number such as 01 B  PIC 9(6) and I only want to extract the first 4 number of A. In Cobol this type of move using MOVE is forbidden, the move I used is MOVE A(1:4) to B.

Comment: I've updated the case, this case is forbidden? I got a error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not forbidden

you just need to

```
03  Field-x4              X(4).
03  Field-94              9(4).




  Move Field-X4            to Field-94
```

Comment: Thanks......my move is not forbidden.....I just got a error in other place of my program...

Answer (score 3):

COBOL provides a few ways to accomplish this sort of assignment. Start with
the declarations outlined in your question:

```
  01 A PIC X(6) VALUE "200030".  
  01 B PIC 9(6).
```

Declare another data item along the lines of:

```
  01 AAAABB.   
     05 AAAA   PIC 9(4).   
     05 BB     PIC 9(2).
```

The `AAAABB` declares a record structure (compound data item) containing two elementary
data items: `AAAA` and `BB`, both of which are numeric. Now you can do either of the
following:

```
  MOVE A(1:4) TO B  ; DISPLAY B
  MOVE A TO AAAABB  ; DISPLAY AAAA
                      DISPLAY BB
```

The displayed output will be:

```
002000  
2000
30
```

Since `AAAABB` is a compound item it has a `PIC X` implicit data type. This in turn
allows you to assign virtually any data value and then decompose it by referring
to its individual components.

Beware, an assignment such as:

```
MOVE A TO AAAA; DISPLAY AAAA
```

This will generally compile (with warnings about truncation) and produce the following
result:

```
0030
```

The most significant digits have been truncated (probably not what you wanted).

COBOL is reasonably flexible with respect to data manipulation. One
thing you should be watching out for (guarding against) is assginment of non-numeric
values to numeric data items as in:

```
MOVE "20++30" TO A
MOVE A TO AAAABB
```

This will "work" just fine until you try to do something like:

```
ADD +1 TO AAAA
```

If you are lucky it will blow up at this point (depending on your compiler and
the actual non-numerics). To guard against this type of error you should always
include logic along the lines of:

```
MOVE A TO AAAABB  
IF (AAAA NOT NUMERIC) OR (BB NOT NUMERIC)  
   PERFORM BAD-DATA-ASSIGNMENT  
END-IF  
ADD 1 TO AAAA
```

Comment: As for the AAAABB example, you said it is implicitly a text, so can we do mathematic things on AAAA and BB?

Comment: Correct, the composite item is untyped (implicitly text) but the lower level elements are explicitly PIC 9 (numeric). Note, that this only works because these numeric items were NOT declared as packed decimal (eg. PIC S9(4) PACKED-DECIMAL) or binary (eg. PIC S9(4) BINARY). COBOL,as do most programming languages, supports several numeric data types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do unions in COBOL with `redefines`. This is from memory but I think it should work:

```
01  YEARMONTH.
    03  YM-FULL                     PIC 9(6).
    03  FILLER REDEFINES YM-FULL.
        05  YM-YEAR                 PIC 9(4).
        05  YM-MONTH                PIC 9(2).

01  JUST-YEAR                       PIC 9(4).

MOVE 200030 TO YM-FULL.
MOVE YM-YEAR TO JUST-YEAR.
```

Comment: I once seen some program do it this way...horrible...Thanks.

Comment: @gunbuster, always happy to provide horrible solutions to people's questions :-)

Comment: Seems fine to me. Wonder what was thought "horrible"?